# How can traslate the default value of the props?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, i18next

I want to traslate the text, i have this code:

```
title: {
  type: String,
  default: function () {
    return this.$t("basic.confirm")
  }
},
```

i am getting this error:

vue.common.dev.js?4650:630 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$t' of undefined"

But when i used in the template, worked fine:

```
{{$t("basic.confirm")}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props are validated before the component instance is created. Therefore "this" keyword is not available at the moment you're attempting to use it, since "this" does not exist yet.

What you can do though is create a computed variable which actually translates the prop and then use it in your template or wherever you want to. Here's the pseudocode:

```
computed: {
      computedTitle: function () {
            // Prop fallback value.
            if (!this.title) {
                return this.$t('basic.confirm');
            }
            // Actual prop value.
            return this.title;
        }
}
```

Comment: how can i put default value?

Comment: Use computedTitle instead of title. Defaulting is implemented inside.